# Storing token values as keys in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to store token values as keys of the firebase database. Something like this:

```
    "Token" : {
  "-KoWsMn9rCIitQeNvixr" : {
    "dK1FjGbNr6k:APA91b...S8JK2d69JpO" : "true" 
  },
  ...
}
```

I am using firebasebaseinstanceid to generate tokens. But the tokens are not stored in the database at all.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String REG_TOKEN="REG_TOKEN";
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Token");

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(REG_TOKEN, recent_token);

    final DatabaseReference newPost = databaseReference.push();
    newPost.child(recent_token).setValue("true");

    }
}
```

I am new to firebase.Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your log statement being called at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

`String userToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

```
        mTokenRef = mRef.child("user_tokens").child(currentUser.getUid()).child(userToken);

        mTokenRef.setValue(true, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference reference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write message", databaseError.toException());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error :( Your profile was not updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

If you add this code in your MainActivity every time your user opens the app it will add a new token to the database. When you send a notification via firebase functions you can remove tokens that no longer work. By doing this you'll be able to send notifications to all of your user's devices and not waste time trying to send notifications to faulty tokens.